# Why gdb plugins don't take effect while remote debugging?

Tags: debugging, gdb, gdbserver

My gdb plugins such as peda, Gdbinit..., work normally while locally debugging.
After I run the commands as below, the plugins environment will always show.

```
gdb testApp

(gdb)b main

(gdb)run
```

The process I do while remotely debugging is as follows.

On PC1:

gdbserver :2345 testApp

On PC2:

```
gdb

(gdb)target remote PC1_IP:2345

(gdb)file testApp

(gdb)b main

(gdb)continue
```

gdb debugging seems good, but the plugins environment never show, although plugins on PC1 and PC2 were both verified to work while locally debugging.

Did I make some mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) instead of peda.

Or if you can, modify the plugin manually. Usually gdb plugins bad at remote does one thing wrong: when they ask for one process is alive, they only consider local cases. They CAN do the same thing remotely, but they don't, as they don't consider the case of remote targets from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, Thiner. I tried pwndbg, it works well, although its installation is not as light-weighted as peda. Thanks for your answer.